# Get restricted user folder when an app requires admin rights and started under admin

Tags: winapi, credentials, admin-rights

There is a Windows app that requires admin rights and this is declared in its manifest. When a restricted user starts it she has to input admin credentials. It's OK and the application works well, but it can't obtain original user folders anymore (ShellAPI returns admin's ones).

Since the application is started under admin initially, there is no point where I can store original user's folder paths to use them later.

Is there a way to get initial restricted user credentials?

Regards,

Comment: This is just how the system works. The process runs under a different user's account. Standard users are not meant to run admin tasks. Generally speaking, the correct way to deal with this is for the app in question to stop demanding admin rights all the time, and only request them for the subset of actions that require them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of your manifest, your app is running as an admin user, not the currently logged in restricted user.  As David Heffernan mentioned, you should redesign your app to not require the entire app to be run elevated.  Delegate your admin tasks to a separate process that runs elevated when needed.

That being said, if you must run your entire app elevated, all is not lost, but you are going to have to do some extra work.

1. Start by getting the Session ID that your elevated app is running in. You can do that using `WTSQuerySessionInformation()` with `WTS_CURRENT_SESSION`, or `ProcessIdToSessionId()` with `GetCurrentProcessId()`, or open the current process's token with `OpenProcessToken()` and then use `GetTokenInformation()`.
2. Once you have the Session ID, use `EnumProcesses()`, `GetProcessImageFileName()` (or equivalent), `OpenProcessToken()`, and  `GetTokenInformation()` to find the instance of `explorer.exe` (or whatever the PC's registered shell app is, which you can find in the Registry) that is running in the same Session ID as your app.
3. When found, you have the user token for that process from `OpenProcessToken()`. Duplicate it using `DuplicateTokenEx()` to get its primary token, and then you can use that token with APIs like `LoadUserProfile()`, `SHGetFolderPath()` and `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` as needed.

Comment: Useful maybe for finding the logged in user's session, but not for gaining access to the logged in user's token necessary for querying most user-related data, like shell folder paths. A SID alone is not enough to get a token.